# AppDelegate confusion when converting code to Marmalade

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, appdelegate, marmalade

I'm converting standalone iPhone code for use as a `Marmalade` extension (a cross-platform mobile dev kit).  You don't need to know about Marmalade though for this question.

My issue is figuring out what to do with `AppDelegate`.  The stand-alone app defines `AppDelegate`, but a `Marmalade` extension is callback based and `Marmalade` has probably already defined its own `AppDelegate`.  So what do I do when my extension is called back?  I don't think I can define another `AppDelegate` can I?  How?  And I don't want to replace the one `Marmalade` already defined.  There are `Marmalade` calls I can make to retrieve the `UIApplication` and pointers to the UIViews `Marmalade` defines, but I don't know how to get my own `AppDelegate` in there.  Can I extend the one that `Marmalade` already defined somehow?

I come from a C/C++ background and this is my first attempt at Objective C, and so far it's got me very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted now.  My confusion had the better of me and it turns out the way the original code used AppDelegate was not vital, so I was able to do away with it for the Marmalade extension and get things working without it.